# Открытие скрытой ссылки при завершении события "Поделиться"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ya-share2

друзья!
У Яндекса существует API, который позволяет разместить на странице блок "Поделиться" с счетчиком поделившихся. Вот код:

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,linkedin" data-counter=""></div>
```

Вот так она выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При завершении события "Поделиться" нужно сделать открытие ранее скрытой ссылки.

Пробовал через скрипт:

```
$(".share-style-1").click(function() {
    $("#book_link").css("display", "inline-block");
    $("#book_link_place").css("display", "none");
});
```

Ссылка не должна открываться, пока пользователь не поделится страницей. До этого стоит просто абзац. Разметка:

```
<p id="book_link_place" class="book_link_place">Здесь будет ссылка для скачивания</p>
<br>
<a href="http://profitmaster.bz/lessons/29_oshibok.pdf" id="book_link" class="book_link" target="_blank">Ссылка на книгу</a>
```

Классы на иконках соцсетей не поддаются обработке. Будет здорово, если кто-то поможет как-то обработать событие.

Answer (score 0):

По [инструкции](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/):

```js
Ya.share2('my-share', {
    hooks: {
        onready: function () {
            alert('блок инициализирован');
        },

        onshare: function (name) {
            alert('нажата кнопка' + name);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div id="my-share" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,linkedin" data-counter=""></div>
```

Обработку `onready` уберите раз она вам не нужна, а в `onshare` поставьте код, который должен выполнятся при расшаривании.

P.S. Тут скрипт выдает ошибку, а на https://jsfiddle.net/obbsvtjL/ он же без ошибок отрабатывает.

Comment: Очень здорово! Забыл добавить, нужно чтобы сохранялись cookie, чтобы пользователь смог обновить страницу, а ссылка для него была открыта.

Comment: @ИгорьВойнов, так кто вам мешает нужные куки сохранить в коде, который будет стоять вместо `alert('нажата кнопка' + name);` из примера?

Comment: Подскажите, как это реализовать?